# How to redirect www to non-www https?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, no-www

I have installed https on my domain. And all this cases are available of my website:

```
http://example.com        // will be redirected to https://example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com    // will be redirected to https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

See? everything will be using https protocol. All fine.

---

Now I need to redirect all `www` to `non-www`. So `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com` should be redirected to `https://example.com` *(in other word, all cases should be redirected to this)*.

Here is my current code in the `/etc/apache2/sites-avalible/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
.
.
.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =lamtakam.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.lamtakam.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]               -- this
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]              -- and this are for www redirection
                                                        -- but doesn't work
</VirtualHost>
```

any idea?

also [lamtakam](https://www.lamtakam.com/) is my exact domain I was talking about, if you need to check something.

---

### Edit:

Currently I have this inside `.htaccess` file on the root of my project:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# this doesn't work on some version of xampp
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want rules in `VirtualHost` then it would be 2 set of rules. If you can keep rules in site root .htaccess then it would be a single rule. I am providing .htaccess rule here:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure you remove your existing rules shown in `VirtualHost` above and you test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Ah thank you .. just one thing, should I remove all `Rewrite` lines inside `Virtualhost`? does your code supports both http to https redirection and www to non-www redirection?

Comment: Since you already have a .htaccess, place this rule just below `RewriteEngine` line and  **remove** every line that starts with `Rewrite` in `Virtualhost`. And yes of course this rule takes care of both `http -> https` and `www` removal.

Comment: I see, thank you so much .. just please take a look at this, and tell me if it is correct: [the content of my `.htaccess` file](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/b8ed348a8f87302cddc4d89639365c92) ?

Comment: Yes that looks correct to me. May be you can move `ErrorDocument` and `Options` before `RewriteEngine`

Comment: I've tested your rule and worked well exactly the same as my expected result. Thank you so much. Also for my information *(another question)*: when I've uploaded my website, `.htacess` file wasn't known for apache. And I've added [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/4a4da3bf2aecb645a474c004125f560f) inside `/etc/apache2/sites-availible/000-default.conf` file and then `.htaccess` worked. now I want to know, can I place [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/4a4da3bf2aecb645a474c004125f560f) inside `.htaccess` too?

Comment: Unfortunately `Directory` is not allowed inside .htaccess