# Converting string but leave characters wrapped in braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

1. I'm converting a user input string (successfully but...)
2. I would like to ignore characters wrapped in braces
3. Also remove the braces in the final output

So for instance if I have this string:

```
$string = "[ABC] This & Text";

function make_post_type($string) {
  $needle   = array('-', ' ');
  $clean    = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]/", "", strtolower($string)); // Remove special characters
  $haystack = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $clean); // Now remove extra spaces

  return str_replace($needle, '_', $haystack);
}
```

returns `abc_this_text`

I would like to return `ABC_this_text`

Comment: Using strtolower twice on the same string may have something to do with it....

Comment: @Andreas That was a mistake, code updated ;)

Comment: I would separate the job in two parts.

One, one who detects the string in the braces, to generate a new output, and then, use **[^a-zA-Z\[\]]+** to replace with **_**, i don't know a lot of php, that's on you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex code in `preg_replace_callback`:

```
function replc($str) {
   return preg_replace_callback (
      '/\[([^]]*)\]|{([^}]*)}|([^][{}]+)/',
      function ($m) {
         return (isset($m[1])?$m[1]:"") .
                (isset($m[2])?$m[2]:"") .
                 (isset($m[3]) ?
                 preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', strtolower($m[3])) : "");
      },
      $str
   );
}
```

**Call it as:**

```
echo replc( "[ABC] This & Text" );
ABC_this_text

echo replc( "abc.Xyz {PQR} Foo-Bar [ABC] This & Text" );
abc_xyz_PQR_foo_bar_ABC_this_text
```

**1st RegEx Details:**

- `[([^]]*)\]`: If we encounter `[...]` then capture inner part in group #1
- `|`: OR
- `{([^}]*)}`: If we encounter `{...}` then capture inner part in group #2
- `|`: OR
- `[^][{}]+`: Match 1+ character that is not `[` and `]` and `{` and `}` and capture in group #3

**2nd RegEx:**

- `\W+`: match 1+ non-word character to be replaced by `_`

Comment: `[]` is not supposed to be there

Comment: upvode .. also since I know you're God of htaccess, can you please take a look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843112/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-https)?

Comment: Thank you, covers all possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to split the string in to an array of words.
If the word contains `[]` remove them only, else do all the other stuff with special characters and strtolower.

Then implode back to string and return

```
$string = "[ABC] This & Text";
Echo make_post_type($string);


function make_post_type($string) {
  $needle   = array('-', ' ');
  $arr = explode(" ", $string);
  foreach($arr as &$a){
     if($a[0] != "[" && $a[-1] != "]"){
        $a = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]/", "", strtolower($a)); // Remove special characters
     }else{
        $a = substr($a, 1,-1);
     }
  }
  $string = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', implode(" ", $arr)); // Now remove extra spaces

  return str_replace($needle, '_', $string);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/rZlaP

Comment: Thank you another great answer

Answer (score 1):

You might use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and use 2 capturing groups.

`\[([A-Z]+)\]|(\w+)`

Use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to check for the capuring groups by index and finally implode using an underscore:

For example:

```
$re = '/\[([A-Z]+)\]|(\w+)/';
$string = "[ABC] This & Text";
preg_match_all($re, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

echo implode('_', array_reduce($matches, function($carry, $item){
    if ($item[1] === "") {
        $carry[] = strtolower($item[2]);
        return $carry;
    }
    $carry[] = $item[1];
    return $carry;

})); //ABC_this_text
```

**Explanation**

- `\[([A-Z]+)\]` Match `[`, capture 1+ uppercase charaters in a group and match `]`. To match everything between the brackets you could use `\[([^]]+)\]` instead.
- `|` Or
- `(\w+)` Capture in a group 1+ word characters. If you want to match more than `\w` you could use a character class and add what you want to match for example `[\w!?]+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rFURMN/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/5QjZg)

Comment: Thanks, this is the easiest for me to understand and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the steps to produce desired string by looking at the problem in another way. First match what you need then replace whitespaces and dashes with `_` at the end:

```
function make_post_type($s) {
    preg_match_all("~({[^{}]*}|\[[^][]*])|[\w\s]+~", $s, $m);
    $s = '';
    foreach($m[0] as $k => $v) {
        $s .= $m[1][$k] ? substr($v, 1, -1) : strtolower($v);
    }
    return preg_replace('~[-\s]+~', '_', $s);
}
```

I enclosed `{[^{}]*}|\[[^][]*]` in parentheses to be able to check for `(bool) $m[1][$k]` later which tells if current value in iteration exists in captured groups returned by `$m[1]` then strip off one leading and trailing character from the string.

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/QKggD)